# rhino-1.6R7.jar and jargs-1.0.jar in yuicompressor-2.4.2.zip

Tags: javascript, dependencies, yui-compressor

I have those two in the lib folder inside yuicompressor-2.4.2.zip. I ran the compressor completely fine without them. What are they for? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't use them; I just have the YUIcompressor .jar file in my build lib and that's it - I think it can work with the JDK-bundled Rhino if it's there.

Comment: Is there Rhino bundled inside JDK 1.6?

Comment: Which version? How can I override it with version?

Comment: This site is becomming useless. Such a simple question and nobody can answer. Time to move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon checking the dependency in yui source code it is clear that jargs class CmdLineParser is directly being used  - and this dependency is also clear when one checks the ant build file lib path.

However, the lib folder is not used by the yui compressor jar itself - it is only used for compiling yui code. The actual yui compressor jar has all the contents of both the rhino and the jargs jar inside it - hence you can really just remove all the other contents of the folders and just use the yui compression jar directly.